# Implanted device in human body that can transmit over long distance

Tags: internal-consistency, hard-science, microscopic

Previously linked [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/216848/can-we-collect-enough-power-from-human-body-to-power-an-implanted-device) (which is closed but already has answers).

Say we have a type of implanted device in human body (say, ear) used to communicate over a distance. I am thinking about a combination of super-capacitor charged over human body to make this device self-powered.

But transmission over a long distance certainly requires a nontrivial amount of power, and being an implanted device makes this trickier. Currently there are [nanoradios](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanoradio) and [this](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2004801/amp/Weve-got-skin-Battery-free-surveillance-device-implanted-flesh.html) kind of design but the transmission range are not enough for long-range (say, over 100m or even over 1 mile) communications.

So my question is, can a miniature implanted device in human body transmit information over a long distance, say 100m or 1 mile (or even longer)? What factors would be important and how?

I want the design to be scientific and based on current technology as much as possible.

Comment: Googling for "antenna human implant" or "wearable antenna" would probably give you the information you need; e.g. https://www.mistralsolutions.com/blog/wearable-antennas-applications-technologies-impact-human-body/

Comment: What information is it transmitting ?

Comment: @StephenG For example record voice and transmit it like a walkie-talkie or mobile phone.

Comment: This will depend greatly on the receiver (also in-ear, or a huge dish?) the data rate (human voice (190kb/s), or downsampled voice (like telefone, 10kb/s), or even just transcribed speech in realtime( 100b/s?)) and whether you allow for the antenna to be outside (camouflaged as a hair, e.g)

Comment: Also, 1 mile can be the range on a field, but as soon as you are near even a single bush, the range in that direction may be down to a few meters... are you talking about 1 mile in urban environment, or on a plain?

Comment: @bukwyrm Thanks for your comment. The receiver is not another implant so it can be just a normal one. I haven’t thought about which kind of voice to transmit, yet doesn’t we need extra space and equipment to make the downsampling and transcription possible? That makes the implant larger right?

Comment: Sure, the implant gets a bit bigger, but not much, if enough funds are available to develop a specialized SoC.

Answer (score 1):

Your enemy is called [signal-to-noise ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio), so you will need to have as much signal-boost on your side as possible:

- more [redundancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_(information_theory)) (means less datarate)
- bigger [antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_(radio)#Gain) (sender, receiver, ideally both)
- more power (dictated your power source, alternatively you restric use-cycles (e.g. once per day for 10 seconds)) - your [signal decays with the square of the distance](https://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/ew-radar-handbook/power-density.htm), so for every doubling of range you need to quadruple your power
- less [absorption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_absorption_rate) (antenna in air, not in watery body, sender, receiver, ideally both)
- line of sight (any frequency you can do with concealable antenna does [not go around](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_range))
- leverage directionality ( [you might gain a few dB by facing your ear/antenna in the direction of the other party](https://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/ew-radar-handbook/power-density.htm), beside skirting the absorption of the signal needing to pass through your head first)

So let's optimize:

- datarate super low, 100bit per second, able to transmit the content of what you speak (your implant does speech-to-text)
- Antenna is several cm long
- You only send short bursts, and not often, but can squander about a Watt on them in return
- the antenna is not even subcutaneous, but only sub-cuticular, or even camouflaged as a hair
- you climb a tree for transmission
- the antennas geometry is directional, and you turn your head juuuust right
- the receiver has a ham-style antenna

> **[35 Miles](http://www.merlin-systems.com/falconry/transmitters/merlin-nano-gold-transmitter.html)**

Comment: Thanks! I wonder what would be the (smallest possible) size of this entire setup?

Comment: If this has been developed with no thought as to budget, the biggest thing will be the capacitor, which scales with the time you'd like to talk. Also, this is the flimsiest part (conceptually), because i am not aware of a cap that could currently do what needs to be done (store harvested energy effciently over a day, then release in a minute) -  say we defeat leakage current, and say we get 100Wh/l, and we need 1Wminute, we'd be at <2ml , so the whole thing would be as big as two lego-person-heads. You can go much smaller by giving it a disposable battery (10 times smaller)

Comment: Thanks. I see. But disposable battery means not rechargeable right? I guess a powerful and rechargeable battery at THAT small size isn’t quite practical?